# Ionic Data Storage

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic4

I have local storage `session_storage`, how can I give to variable `ttt` value `dogovor` from `session_storage`?

```js
ttt: any = this.storage.get('session_storage', 'dogovor');
```

Sample above is not working.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To set an item

```
this.storage.set('YOUR_KEY', 'YOUR_VALUE');
```

for eg:

```
this.storage.set('session_storage', 'dogovor');
```

To get the item

```
this.storage.get('YOUR_KEY').then((value) => {
  console.log(value);
});
```

for eg:

```
// declare 
private ttt = '';

// get data from storage
this.storage.get('session_storage').then((value) => {
  console.log(value);
  this.ttt = value;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are basically two functions to store and retrieve data,

Ionic 3: *@ionic/storage* functions `get` y `set`

Ionic 4: *@ionic-native/native-storage/ngx* functions `getItem` y `setItem`

1) to store a `value` related to a `key` use,

Ionic 3
`this.storage.set('key', 'value')`

Ionic 4 returns a `Promise`

```
let value = null;
this.storage.set('key', 'value').then(
  () => console.log('Value stored!'),
  error => console.log(error)
);
```

2) to retrieve from store a `value` using the related `key` use `get`, this function returns a `Promise`, an example

Ionic 3

```
let value = null;
this.storage.get('key').then(
  data => value = data,
  error => console.log(error)
);
```

Ionic 4, similar to Ionic 3 just change function name `set` to `setItem`